# Как записать значение в текстовый файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как записать значение в текстовый файл, в конец определённой строки?

Есть файл с n-ым количеством строк, как мне добавить значение в 2 строку что бы оно было в конце этой строки. Этот код добавляет значение в начало строки:

```
f = open("example.TXT", "r", encoding='utf-8')
contents = f.readlines()
f.close()

contents.insert(1, 'bla-bla-bla')

f = open("example.TXT", "w", encoding='utf-8')
contents = "".join(contents)
f.write(contents)
f.close()
```

Как сделать так что бы он добавлял это значение в конец определённой строки строки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. считать весь файл в список через `readlines()`
2. изменить элемент списка с нужным индексом (позиция строки)

   ```
    lines = file.readline();

    lines[index] = lines[index][:-1] + my_text + "\n"
   ```

вначале главное у нужной строки отрезать `\n` в конце

3. перезаписать файл (записать новый список) через `writelines()`